# Is it a coincidence to calculate Rutherford scattering using the first order Born approximation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering-cross-section, born-oppenheimer-approximation

It is well-known that we can use Born first approximation to calculate the differential cross section. To be precise, firstly we modify the potential as Yukawa potential
$$V(r)=\dfrac{\alpha e^{-r/a}}{r}, $$
and plug it into the Born approximation formula
$$f(\theta,\phi)=-\dfrac{\mu}{2\pi\hbar^2}\int{\rm d}^3x_1V(\vec{r}_1)\exp(i\vec{q}\cdot\vec{r}_1) , $$
where $\vec{q}$ is the change of momentum during the scattering $\vec{q}=\vec{k}_f-\vec{k}_i$. After the integral take the limit $a \to \infty$ to return to Coulomb potential. You can find the final resalt is precisely the Rutherford formula, without any slight difference.

On the other hand, actually for Coulomb potential scattering process can be solved analytically from Schödinger equation, and our task is to give the aymptotic behavior of the solution, which turns out to be a confluent supergeometric function. What's astonishing is that by brute force this way we get the same answer by using only first order of Born approximation, varying in $f(\theta,\phi)$ only by a phase factor! But by no means a long-range Coulomb potential can be viewed as a perturbation. Is it a coincidence? Or are there some  significant physical mechanism behind the appearance?

Thanks in advance!